# Wrong paths in Codename One preferences

Tags: codenameone

When I need to input a path in Codename One preferences, for example to set up the icon or the certificates to use, I use the browse button. However the path that is then filled up in the associated field leads to the jre (java runtime environnement) folder instead of the parent folder of the file I selected.

Moreover the path is preceded by "file:" where it should not be there.

Here is an example to make it clearer :
 [image: wrong path]

As a workaround I manually paste the folder path where the file I want to use resides, and then paste it in the field. So as it is a little bit annoying, I was wondering if I could do something to make it work as it should ?

Please note : my setup involves Eclipse Mars running under Linux 64 with Oracle's Java 8 JDK.

Any help appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be related to [this issue](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1882), I wasn't able to reproduce it in full although I did fix the `file:` prefix. The paths I got were correct despite all my attempts.

My only guess is that this might be an issue that affected an earlier version of the tool so I've added a version number to the title (`1.13` in my current version). If this still happens in the next plugin update and the title of the preferences is `1.13` or newer I'd like to know.

Comment: Right the link you gave describes the same behaviour! I'll keep you posted. By the way, I wanted to look at the source code for the preference menu but was a bit lost. Is it in [UserPreferences](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/f96a2d46aa2f51b9e382d63ef1ef359963a7f0d2/CodenameOneDesigner/src/com/l2fprod/common/swing/UserPreferences.java) ?

Comment: Preferences is a part of the plugin which isn't open source. The plugin and the build server are the pieces of Codename One that aren't open.

Comment: I've just updated the Project Libs to version 128 and the CN1 plugin to version 1.0.0 20160812 (Eclipse does not offer me a later version) and restarted Eclipse. In this plugin version the behaviour regarding the issue is still the same ("file" is added as well as the jdk path) although this does not seem to be the latest version you corrected (title bar does not show the version, only "Codename One Preferences")

Comment: Eclipse is a bit out of date compared to the other plugins. We'll try to update it as soon as we can.